# How can I get serverless-webpack to work with babel.v8 to solve - Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions?

Tags: node.js, babeljs, serverless-framework, serverless-webpack-plugin

**What went wrong?**

Babel Migration from 7.x to 8.x
Node Migration from 8.x to 10.x

**What was the config you used?**

Changed targets in .babelrc from 8.10 to 10.14.1
Changed runtime in serverless.yml from 8.10 to runtime: nodejs10.14.1

**What stacktrace or error message from your provider did you see?**

```
ERROR in ./getCaseRecord.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In /Users/MyDocs/DevOps/QuickAutoTags/services/v2.crm-case-record-api/node_modules/babel-preset-stage-3/lib/index.js
    at createDescriptor (/Users/MyDocs/DevOps/QuickAutoTags/services/v2.crm-case-record-api/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:178:11)
    at items.map (/Users/MyDocs/DevOps/QuickAutoTags/services/v2.crm-case-record-api/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:50)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptors (/Users/MyDocs/DevOps/QuickAutoTags/services/v2.crm-case-record-api/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:29)
    at createPresetDescriptors (/Users/MyDocs/DevOps/QuickAutoTags/services/v2.crm-case-record-api/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:101:10)
    at presets (/Users/MyDocs/DevOps/QuickAutoTags/services/v2.crm-case-record-api/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:47:19)
    at mergeChainOpts (/Users/MyDocs/DevOps/QuickAutoTags/services/v2.crm-case-record-api/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:320:26)
    at /Users/MyDocs/DevOps/QuickAutoTags/services/v2.crm-case-record-api/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:283:7
    at buildRootChain (/Users/MyDocs/DevOps/QuickAutoTags/services/v2.crm-case-record-api/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:120:22)
    at loadPrivatePartialConfig (/Users/MyDocs/DevOps/QuickAutoTags/services/v2.crm-case-record-api/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/partial.js:85:55)
    at Object.loadPartialConfig (/Users/MyDocs/DevOps/QuickAutoTags/services/v2.crm-case-record-api/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/partial.js:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/MyDocs/DevOps/QuickAutoTags/services/v2.crm-case-record-api/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:144:26)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/MyDocs/DevOps/QuickAutoTags/services/v2.crm-case-record-api/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:3:103)
    at _next (/Users/MyDocs/DevOps/QuickAutoTags/services/v2.crm-case-record-api/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:5:194)
    at /Users/MyDocs/DevOps/QuickAutoTags/services/v2.crm-case-record-api/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:5:364
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/MyDocs/DevOps/QuickAutoTags/services/v2.crm-case-record-api/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:5:97)
    at Object._loader (/Users/MyDocs/DevOps/QuickAutoTags/services/v2.crm-case-record-api/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:224:18)
    at Object.loader (/Users/MyDocs/DevOps/QuickAutoTags/services/v2.crm-case-record-api/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:60:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/MyDocs/DevOps/QuickAutoTags/services/v2.crm-case-record-api/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:55:12)
```

**Here is what is in my `.babelrc` file:**

```
{
    "plugins": [],
    "presets": [
        ["env", {"node": "10.14.1"}],
        "stage-3"
    ]
}
```

**Here are my dependencies in my `package.json`:**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.350.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-source-map-support": "^2.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "eslint": "^5.15.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "serverless-offline": "^5.0.0",
    "serverless-webpack": "^5.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.16.2",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.6.0"
  },
```

What do you think? I really want to stay current and use the most recent version of babel if at all possible. Does anyone know if serverless-webpack supports babel.v8 yet??

If so, how can I get them to work together considering the above info?

Thanks!

Comment: Try running `npx babel-upgrade` to see if theres anything missing with your configuration.

Comment: @Alex please see the answer I just posted and let me know what you think in terms of any consequence I may face down the road without babel-loader. Not sure if this was the best approach but it helped out for now. Thanks either way sir!

Comment: I know this answer is old, but there is really no need to use babel with a serverless deployment, anyway it is entire up to you, but bringing 8 dependencies to do something that is really not necessary seems a bit too much.

Comment: There are other considerations Im trying to account for in that project... so yeah forgive my habit of never providing the minimum viable example on SO. Furthermore, since you understand what I'm going for here, maybe you could help me with the proper way to approach this. I came up with the question, and due to lack of any input I was forced to find my own answer... do you have any feedback that would make this better??? Seems like you might; how would you approach this babel implementation in 2021??? Ultimately Im trying to get my server less lambdas updated to the latest and greatest @Madeo

Comment: Yes, the best answer I could give you is not to use babel unless you really need (TypeScript or frontend). It will save you a lot of development time. Maybe I made it sounds like it was your fault, well it is not. I am just saying that if you can avoid Babel just do it =).

Comment: @Madeo I listened to you and got rid all of those bloated dependencies. What say you about Webpack on serverless??? Do I even need that too??? Why would I want to use Webpack??? I got rid of it and my endpoints deployed perfectly... dont know if they even work yet tho!  This is probably the best advice I have gotten on SLS issues. Please add as an answer and will mark as accepted please! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case it helps, the only way I could get it to work was to comment out `babel-loader` as such:

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        // TODO: This was the fix to sls deploy
        // loader: "babel-loader",
        include: __dirname,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
```

Not sure if this is the best work-around but it helped me solve the current issue I was working on.